# How can I host AppWidgets in my app (launcher)?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, android-launcher

I am making a launcher app replacement for home screen in Android.
I want to add widgets to it (native app widgets). How can I ?
I tried many methods and they all either didn't work or worked with bugs (which I couldn't solve).

Anybody knows of a way to implement AppWidgets ?

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://coderender.blogspot.ch/2012/01/hosting-android-widgets-my.html

Seems to be working fine.. :)

Comment: It has too many problems. Like undefined variables : R.id.REQUEST_PICK_APPWIDGET

Comment: great answer. perfect link.